# Putting a custom view into a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a regular-style UITableView—the one that has a white background and gray horizontal lines to separate the rows.

I have another custom UIView that is just a 100x100 rectangle filled with redColor.

How can I put the latter into the former, such that it appears **over** the horizontal lines, but is still a “part” of the table view in the sense that when I scroll the table view around, the red view scrolls with it? In fact, I should also be able to put my finger on the red area and scroll the table view.

Once again, if the red view is placed to overlap some horizontal lines, it should appear **over** the lines. Sadly, when I just add the red view as a subview to the table view, the horizontal lines go over the red view; see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooaf0.png).

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Do you want that the red view will hide the lines content ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you are trying to add the view a above the lines (hide the lines) try to use `– bringSubviewToFront:` to take it to the front of the table view.

```
[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:redView];
```

**ELSE**

Add the view to the  `self.tableView.tableHeaderView` this will place it above the table view and will scroll with the table view.

```
UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc]init];
  redView.frame = //set the frame 
  redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = redView;
```

Good Luck

Comment: `bringSubviewToFront:` did the trick, thanks. There was no need for me to call it multiple times (in places like `scrollViewDidScroll:` or `layoutSubviews`) as some others here suggested. I just initialized my red view in `viewWillAppear:` (in the `UITableViewController` subclass) and then called `bringSubviewToFront:` in `viewDidAppear` (I put the red view in an instance variable). This worked great for me.

Answer (score 12):

The correct place to handle the stacking order of your red square is in the `layoutSubviews` method.  The table view sends itself `layoutSubviews` any time it adds or removes subviews (and at other times).

You need to make a subclass of `UITableView` that has a reference to the red square:

```
@interface MyTableView : UITableView

@property (weak, readonly) IBOutlet UIView *redSquare;

@end
```

You can initialize `redSquare` in whatever way you want.  I just put it in my nib along with the table view, and moved it to be a subview of the table view in `awakeFromNib`:

```
@implementation MyTableView

@synthesize redSquare = _redSquare;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self addSubview:self.redSquare];
}
```

Anyway, to actually make sure the red square is always on top of the table cells and grid lines, override `layoutSubviews` like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.redSquare];
}
```

Comment: Exactly. UITableView relayouts whenever a cell is added or removed. The cells are actually just subviews of the table, and could be in any order.

Comment: Could you tell me how you do what you mention in case I’m not using a XIB file? How would I specify a custom subclass without using XIB? I initialize my `UITableViewController` subclasses programmatically, and everything I do is in code only.

Comment: Somewhere your code says `[[UITableView alloc] init...]`.  You need to make it say `[[MyTableView alloc] init...]` and set its `redSquare` property.

Comment: or if you're just using the `UITableViewController`'s default table view, create your own instance of `MyTableView` and assign it to the controller's `view` and `tableView` properties.

Comment: People keep saying "Never subclass UITableView" and how they got by for years without doing that. I can't figure out how to get a layoutSubviews call without subclassing it. Subclassing it turned out to be easy, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can usually do what you need by implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods like `scrollViewDidScroll:` in your table view's delegate instead of subclassing `UITableView`.  But sometimes it's easier or necessary to subclass `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this view to UITableView as subview:

```
[tableView addSubview:myRedView];
```

See [userInteractionEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled) property in order to handle interaction and scrolling.

Comment: The problem with this is that the horizontal lines of the table view overlap the red view. The red view should be **over** the horizontal lines. Any further ideas?

Comment: @Enchilada, No, red view lies on the top of the UITableView. I just created from scratch new project and write 3 lines of code in viewWillAppear, see result here - http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/3584/screenshot20120131at112.png

Comment: Strange, that’s not what happens here. Here is my screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooaf0.png Any ideas why our results differ?

Comment: No ideas(. I cann't reproduce this bug in my project. Really I don't know why you are getting this strange situation.

Answer (score 0):

Make your view a subview of any normal subview of the `UITableView`: a header, a footer or any `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: That would not guarantee it to be in front of the dividers. In fact that would not even guarantee it to be visible outside of its containter view

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've described can best be achieved using a `UITableViewCell` or even a subview of the header.  A cell has the inherent ability to scroll the table and can be customized any way you like it.  It's essentially a view.

In your situation, for example, you may want the red box to appear by default at the top of the table.  You would make the first cell a 'red box' cell, where you would insert your red box into the cell's content view.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem is basically, that the UITableViewCells of a UITableView are added as Subviews dynamically, and you cannot control wether they are added in front of or behind your view.

So to keep your view at the front, you need to get it back there every time cells may be added, which occurs when the UITableView scrolls.

I would suggest you try adding your custom view as a subview and then override `-scrollViewDidScroll` like so:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll {
    [super scrollViewDidScroll];
    // myCustomView is your custom view referenced in an IVar
    [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:myCustomView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your viewWillAppear delegate with these lines

```
UIView *redView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,30, 100, 100)];
redView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.tableView addSubview:redView];
```