# How to add a white view under cell in to the UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I will like add a white view under all cell in to the UITableView, because TableView background is Clear Color, and when Cell N is one or two under these is clear.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNHWh.png)

I will like under these cells view color will white.

P.D. Sorry, my english is so bad. =(

Comment: why not set the cell's conentView background color?

Comment: i have elements on table view background, i will like show it.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067533/putting-a-custom-view-into-a-uitableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned above that there are UIView elements on your UITableView background so setting he background color of it would not work, correct?

You could try setting the background color of the UITableViewCell itself, and add any of your custom views as subviews on the cell.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up tableview's footer view, and make it with a white background.

Comment: I tried, but when you scroll the footer will show above the cells.

Comment: Then try to make the tableview's height equal to screen height.